# Objects not visible in EEVEE renderings

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, transparency, customization, settings

My objects are not showing up in EEVEE renderings. They also aren't showing up in Viewport Shading: Rendered. You can see their outline and they show a checkerboard pattern as if they are transparent but also block whatever is behind them. Rendering works fine using CYCLES and Workbench so it seems it's an issue particular to EEVEE. Moreover, I don't know what I've done but it seems to affect *all* my files including ones that used to work fine that I have rendered successfully and new ones I just made with a few test objects. In Viewport Shading: Materials the objects are outlined in white or coloured dots. Is that a clue?

I've Googled the problem but can't find anything obviously useful, e.g.

- yes, I've tried to unhide everything using Alt+H
- yes, the camera is definitely pointing at the objects because I can see them in Viewport Shading: Solid and render them in Workbench.
- yes, I have tried changing the lights.

Have I stupidly hit some shortcut key which might affect the global preferences somehow?

Could it be an issue with the recent Windows update or available memory?

Many thanks

Blender Render using Workbench:
[image: Blender Render using Workbench]
Blender Render using cycles:
[image: Blender Render using cycles]
Blender Render using EEVEE:
[image: Blender Render using EEVEE showing missing object problem]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thanks! I uploaded the new very simple file I made which shows the same basic problem. It might be something very silly that I've forgotten.

Comment: please once you've uploaded, share the URL it will generate

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/266bfddf5f7245879dd4d56944028f31

Comment: With slight changes:
https://pasteall.org/blend/8a8c7115d7ca427ba9cbbe4e03792565

Comment: it works fine here, do you have a AMD? there are some problems with the latest driver...

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that it works for you. I suspect it's an issues specific to my machine or preferences. I don't know what an AMD is but a driver issue would make sense. Perhaps the latest Window update has blocked somehow.  Thanks for your efforts. I will look into AMD further.

Comment: AMD is a graphic card, I'm not 100% sure but it may be a problem with your graphic card

Comment: maybe try to enable High Quality Normals in Render panel > Performance

Comment: I have tried enabling "High Quality Normals" and updating my display adaptor drivers. Neither of these actions fixed the problem. I also checked the update history of my drivers and neither of them have updated within the last two weeks. Therefore, rolling back to previous version will not work. My problem remains unsolved.

Comment: ok weird, I hope someone will explain  :/

Comment: Many thanks for trying. I'm going to revisit the problem in a couple of weeks in the hope that further updates sort it out. Thankfully, I don't *need* Blender EEVEE this week but two weeks ago would've been a disaster.